# Unity 2D Enemies don't take damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in unity and game development. I'm trying to build a combat 2d game, but I can't damage enemies and I'm banging my head against a wall for 1 week, because I can't see where is the error.

This is my Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    //[SerializeField] private float attackCooldown;
    [SerializeField] private float range;
    [SerializeField] private int damage;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask enemyLayer;


    public Transform AttackPoint;

    //private float cooldownTimer = Mathf.Infinity;

    private Animator anim;
    private Enemy enemyHealth;




    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<Enemy>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
            Attack();
            Debug.Log("attacking");
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (AttackPoint == null)
            return;

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(AttackPoint.position, range);

    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, range, enemyLayer);

        foreach (Collider2D Enemy in hitEnemies)
        {

            if (Enemy.CompareTag("Enemy"))
                Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
                Debug.Log("Enemy Hit!");
                
        }
    } 
}
```

And this is the Enemy script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float startingHealth;

    public float currentHealth;
    public Animator anim;
    
    private bool dead;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float _damage)
    {

        //currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth - _damage, 0, startingHealth);

        if (currentHealth > 0)
        {
        //hurt anim
            Debug.Log("damage taken");
        }

        if (!dead)
        {
            //dead anim
            GetComponent<EnemyPatrol>().enabled = false; //enemy cannot move while he is dead
            GetComponent<EnemyMelee>().enabled = false;  //enemy cannot attack

            dead = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update() //for testing
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
            TakeDamage(1);
    }
}
```

I tried testing it with the debug, and unity tells me that I'm hitting the enemy but without damaging him.
I tried also to damage the enemy pressing P for testing, and this works.
Thank you guys in advance for your help,
Federico.

Built Player and Enemy scripts. The player can be damaged by enemies but the player cannot damage the enemies.

Comment: First of all have in mind that in `if (Enemy.CompareTag("Enemy"))
                Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
                Debug.Log("Enemy Hit!");` the log will always happen even if the tag is missing ... you want to add some `{ }` around those two lines ... -> is it possible you forgot to tag your objects?

Comment: The Enemy component is tagged correctly. Should I change even the subcomponents' tag?

Answer (score 0):

In your attack function, here:

```
            if (Enemy.CompareTag("Enemy"))
                Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
                Debug.Log("Enemy Hit!");
```

Only the TakeDamage line is inside the if statement, the log is not so it always executes. YOu need to change it look like this:

```
            if (Enemy.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
                Debug.Log("Enemy Hit!");
            }
```

So the issue is therefore that CompareTag is returning false, if you're seeing the enemy hit log and not the take damage log. The enemy does not have the correct tag.

Comment: I tried, but now hit and damage messages don't work. I checked the tag on the enemy component and it is correct, even the layer.

Comment: Definitely the tag is wrong. Try replacing Enemy.CompareTag("Enemy") with Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>() != null

Comment: Tried, but still can't see "enemy hit" or "damage taken".

Comment: Then you are not hitting any enemies with your physics overlap. Perhaps the enemyLayer variable is wrong, or your circle is in the wrong place.

Comment: I checked the inspector and the layermask is correct. I tried also to move the circle further to be sure that I'm hitting the enemy. It doesn't work, really don't know what to do

Comment: Focus on debugging the overlap circle because that is 100% where your issue is. Expand the circle, remove the enemyLayer parameter (I think if you don't pass in one it defaults to scanning everything), print the name of the game object of every hit object. Try all of these things and you'll figure it out. I can't help much more beyond that because I'm not sitting next to you.

Comment: Your compare "Enemy" tag is returning false every time.  

You said that adding curly braces stopped the messages too.  The way you had it written before, the if statement only ran the line right after the if statement.  Then you added curly braces and it stopped running altogether, because your if statement is returning false.